# UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: mybusiness version: v4

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-my-business-api

I'm trying to access accounts and locations from my Google MyBusiness API. I defined an OAuth2 key and authorized APIs in GCP console, once I run my python code `run.py` I get this error :

> googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: mybusiness
> version: v1

**run.py**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from pathlib import Path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from libs.gcp import gcp
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

 def run():

    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"]

    creds = None
    if Path("token.json").exists():
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
        print("m")
        print(creds)
        # Build the API client
        service = build("mybusiness", "v1", credentials=creds)

        # Get the list of locations for the authenticated account
        locations = service.accounts().locations().list(
            parent='accounts/112827745/locations'.format(account_id='myaccount')).execute()

        # Print the list of location names
        for location in locations.get('locations', []):
            print(location.get('name'))
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            print(creds)
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

I tried to run with `service = build("mybusiness", "v4", credentials=creds)` and `service = build("mybusiness", "v4.0", credentials=creds)` but got the same error.

My API is well configured because I am able to get data from postman so it's not a token or API problem.

Does anyone see the solution? Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retrieving accounts and locations, try `"mybusinessbusinessinformation"` as your service name instead of `"mybusiness"`.

Like this:
`service = build("mybusinessbusinessinformation", "v1", credentials=creds)`

I found that name by looking at the service name on [this GBP documentation page](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest#discovery-document)

Comment: Now I got this error do you kno TypeError: Parameter "parent" value "accounts/112827745/locations" does not match the pattern "^accounts/[^/]+$"
Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: You do not need "locations" at the end of your parent value, "accounts/112827745"